# Responsive mockup for img slider

Tags: html, css

Page template consists of header with menu, content with images slider and footer with text.

```
<style>
    header {height: 60px;}
    footer {height: 20px;}
</style>
<body>
<header>
 <!-- menu -->
</header>
<div class="content">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="item">
      <img href="" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img href="" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img href="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <!-- some text -->
</footer>
</body>
```

Content has only the images slider. Images have very big size and sizes differs. So images have to fill maximum free space by width and height. So the template will fill the whole screen without scrollbars. 
What style are needed for content and img tags ? 
Because it's responsive, width and height for content must be 100%. But it doesn't work. 
Bootstrap 2 is used in project.

https://jsfiddle.net/84nqq8gu/ - simple example

Comment: Bootstrap 2? 3.3.6 is the way to fly at the moment.

Comment: You'll need big size images.! give the img tag height and width of 100% and for header and footer - keep them fixed.!

Comment: Thanks. But it's an old project. I'm not sure that I want to update bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
    margin-top: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

use max-width and max-height. Either one will fill the available space depending on which fits best.

Comment: Perhaps you have some padding in the upper element?

Comment: No. I have added jsfiddle with example. You can see there is no any paddings and margins. Only elements height

Comment: I am not seeing any scrollbar. Tried with chrome 47.0.2526.73.